# Surjective map from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Surjective map between $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.
I am confused as to how this is even possible to create.

Comment: No sorry, I dont believe there are any maps from these two sets it would be illogical if there are.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
f(n)=\begin{cases}
 \frac n2 & \text{if n is even}\\
-{n-1\over 2} & \text{if n is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

$f:\mathbb Z^+\mapsto \mathbb Z$ is a bijection and thus a surjection also.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}^+\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by
\begin{align}
\varphi(m)=\begin{cases}
-\frac{m}{2},& m \text{ is even}\\
\frac{m-1}{2}, & m \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
is such an example. Remark $\varphi=-f$ where $f$ is defined in Saikai Prime's answer.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Comment: One problem,  $0$ has no pre-image and hence $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Oh yeah, now everything is ok.